# Creating a dynamic anonymous types variables

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

Can I create an anonymous type variable and later on add more Properties?

E.g.
`var x = new { Name = "Ahmed" };` and want to add `Age` to it?
how can I do this?

Another question: i saw on some blogs a type `AnonymousType` what is the name space for this class? here is am example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AnonymousTypesInCSharp.aspx

Comment: Such an object is often called an "expando object". C# does not *implement* expando objects, though C# 4 will support *calling* expando objects via the "dynamic" keyword. Consider using Python or JScript or some other language that natively supports expando objects if that's what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First question - you can't.

Second question - AnonymousType is the type the author of that article created. You have to download the source for his project to use that type.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant.

2nd question: No such thing, it might refer to compiler generated class which you have no access to.

Answer (score 0):

No, and It would not be efficient for Your application.
Are You convinced that You don't want to introduce some kind of class?

```
using System;
class Generic{

   public void doSomething(){}

   private string name;
   private string _othreFeature;

}
```

You could extend it with new features, whenever You want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly logical question... I work with Java and C# both and this is a big pet peeve of mine... Matter of fact almost every language out there has some sort of Anonymous type lol... PHP, JavaScript, C#, vb (all), and the list goes on..

It's a very useful feature to have when you're basically throwing data into an object and you don't need a class for it created.

Matter of fact this is exactly what LINQ utilizes..

```
var someObject (can be interable/Enumerable) = 
    from p in products
    where p.id == 123
    select new { productid };
```

blah blah you get the idea.. It's very useful...  :-)

Cheers!

Comment: I know this is very old, but your last line seems to be in error and I'm just clarifying for other readers.  If you just want the product ID from a LINQ statement, you wouldn't use select(prod => new { prod.ID }), you'd just do select(prod =? prod.ID} which doesn't use anonymous types at all.  If you instead however wanted to pair the name up with the ID, then yes, you'd use new{prod.Name, prod.ID} which would be an anonymous type. Again, I know... very old but still.