# Using 'Dynamic' to Assist Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, anonymous-types

I want the ability to grab an anonymous type from my view, that was established by the corresponding controller.  According to [this article](http://hugoware.net/blog/simplify-using-anonymous-types), such an ability becomes possible in C# 4.0 with the 'dynamic' keyword.  However, when I try to find an actual example I find answers ranging from it kinda '[is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111175/using-dynamic-in-c-sharp-to-access-field-of-anonymous-type-possible)' to it kinda '[is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519851/creating-a-dynamic-anonymous-types-vairables).'

In my case, I have a controller creating this:

```
XElement headings = XElement.Parse(part.TagList);
var items = from heading in headings.Descendants("heading")
            select new {
                name = heading.Attribute("name").Value, 
                tags = heading.Attribute("tags").Value,
                content = shapeHelper.List() //This is a dynamic object!!!
            }; //can I add 'as dynamic;' here????
```

In short it would be nice if, without a static type, my view could simply reach into the model like this:

```
@{
//Currently this next line returns an error saying that 
//'object' contains no method 'Count'
int foo = Model.items.Count();  

//This 'foreach' works.
foreach(dynamic lineItem in Model.items){
  //But this does not work. Gives another "'object' has no definition for 'name'"
  <p>@lineItem.name</p>     }
}
```

Possible?

Comment: Justin's suggestion below should work. I just tend to be weary about using `dynamic` types in MVC views since for some reason I always end up having to cast my objects to something usable (`string`, `int`, etc) to avoid errors about using dynamic types in views (even when using the `ViewBag`).

Comment: to ask an obvious mvc-good-practices question - why not just use a viewmodel here (the standard recommendation)? why does an anonymous type become a requirement as opposed to a view model populated, strongly types, compile time errors caught, not susceptible to magic string issues/typos, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but you could always use the [`ViewBag`](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx):

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Items = from heading in headings.Descendants("heading")
                select new {
                    name = heading.Attribute("name").Value, 
                    tags = heading.Attribute("tags").Value,
                    content = shapeHelper.List()
                };
```

**View**

```
ViewBag.Items.First().content;
```

Comment: Your answer implies that I will get the same result with the model as well - as long as I don't declare its type in the view?  I'm actually using Orchard CMS (built on MVC3) so I don't actually have access to the ViewBag - or at least I don't think I do.

Comment: It turns out my question was malformed; Some of the info I gave was bad.  I've corrected my question and I've learned that it simply is not possible to use the `ViewBag.Items.First().content` syntax.  The problem is that 'content' is a staticly-typed property which the view knows nothing about.  Having the view cast items from the collection to 'dynamic' does not help, because staticly-typed properties of an anonymous type have nothing to do with properties on a dynamic object.  To use a dynamic object in the view means I must use a dynamic object in the controller too (not anonymous-type).